# How to change drop down list selected index and visibility using another drop down list in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a drop down list like this in my asp.net application,

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlChanges" CssClass="selectstyle" onchange="javascript:ddlChangesChanged();"> 
<asp:ListItem Text="-- Select -- " Value="-1"></asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Text="Status Change" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Product Name Change" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>       
<asp:ListItem Text="Category Change" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So, when user selects "Status Change" from the list, another dropdown list with following values appears,

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlStatus" CssClass="selectstyle"  Style="visibility: hidden;"> 
<asp:ListItem Text="-- Select -- " Value="-1"></asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Fixed" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>       
<asp:ListItem Text="Cancelled" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CssClass="selectstyle" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"></asp:Button>
```

If user does not select any value from the drop down list (ddlStatus), I am displaying an alert message ("You must select a status.") using JavaScript in the btnUpdate click event,

```
if (this.ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Value.Trim() == "-1")
{
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('You must select a status.');</script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
}
```

But after this, my page refreshes and drop down list **ddlChanges** has "Status Change" (previously selected item) as selected item and drop down list (ddlStatus) gets hidden. I want ddlChanges drop down list to have -- Select -- as the selected item and **ddlStatus** should be visible.

How can I do that?

Comment: So why don't you reset your `ddl`s to the required state inside the `btnUpdate` click? `ddlStatus.Style= "visibility: hidden";` and `ddlChanges.SelectedItem = ...`

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not rewrite the changes later?

Comment: Edit your question, you probably meant "...ddlChanges drop down list to have **Status Change** as the selected item and ddlStatus should be visible."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a full postback (all changes on client get reset, except the posted back input values) - so either do a client (javascript) validation (best option), or switch to ajax partial postback (faster option), or simply just change this (slowest option):

```
if (this.ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Value.Trim() == "-1")
{
    ddlStatus.Attributes["style"] = null;
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('You must select a status.');</script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

btnUpdate click event raises the server side code, and the server does not know about what the user has selected on client. one option could be use client side validation to avoid Post back and preserve the selections at client

Comment: Server knows what the user selected on client - the value gets posted back. What the server does not know is that ddlStatus was made visible on client - it is returned back hidden again.